# Pass new parent object id to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save parent as well as child object at the same time using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Code in controller's new method:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.instances.build
end
```

and form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= link_to "Add New Instance", new_project_instance_path(@project), id: "new_link", remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

The route entry for this is:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :instances
end
```

And the fields that need to be displayed `instances/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :instances do |i| %>
  <%= i.input :user_id %>
  <%= i.input :password %>
  <%= i.input :service_url %>  
<% end %>
```

The issue here `project_id` being `:nil`, it is giving error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"instances", :project_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:project_id]
```

I need to somehow call `<%= render 'cdd_instances/form', form: f %>`, so that the fields get rendered below the Project details, how should I implement this?

Comment: how your `routes` look like?

Comment: updated with the `routes`

Comment: you can not pass nil as id in routes as `@project` is nil, you should use `f.fields_for :instances_attributes`

Comment: I have added the code for that too, let me know wht need to be done

Answer (score 0):

I think your @project is null you have to pass like:

```
 new_project_instance_path(project_id: (@project || ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are not able to pass non-persisted `@project` to create this `link_to` url.

I believe you are looking for something like: [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <h3>Instances</h3>
  <div id="instances">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :instances do |instance| %>
      <%= render 'instance_fields', f: instance %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add instance', f, :instances %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Cheers!